# Django Foreignkey or onetoone models create,edit,view within an Modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hy all,

I am building an HR management system, i have below models

```
class EmployeeDetails(models.Model):
EMP_NO = models.CharField(max_length=6,primary_key=True,validators=[Validation])
EMP_First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False,validators=[Validation])
passport = models.OneToOneField('PassportDetails',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='employee_passport',null=False,blank=False)
visa = models.ForeignKey(Visa_Details,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False,blank=False)

class PassportDetails(models.Model):
Passport_No =models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False,primary_key=True,validators=[Passport_Validation])

class Visa_Details(models.Model):
VISA_NO=models.CharField(max_length=19,null=False,primary_key=True,validators=[Visa_Validators])#
```

in admin panel we can see below buttons and features
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRfcI.png)
i want same feature for my below custom buttons
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrzeY.png)

i tried using inline-forms, calling models normal way but it requires URL/int:passport_id/ but when rendering it wont load it because when creating a new employee details their wont be any id,
i hope iam clear.

```
           <th>Passport No:</th>
           <td>
               {{ form.passport }}
           </td>
            <div class="Add" >
               <a href="#" data-tip="Add Passport" onclick="PassportAction('ADD')" id="AddClick">
                 <box-icon name='plus-medical' color="green" size="xs">
                 </box-icon>
              </a>
            </div>
              <div class="Edit">
               <a href="#" data-tip="Edit Passport" onclick="PassportAction('EDIT')" id="EditClick">
                 <box-icon name='edit-alt' color="green" size="xs" class="Ico">
                 </box-icon>
              </a>
            </div>
                <div class="Show">
               <a href="#" data-tip="Show Passport" onclick="PassportAction('VIEW')" id="ViewClick">
                 <box-icon name='expand-vertical' color="green" size="xs" class="Ico">
                 </box-icon>
              </a>
            </div>

              <script>
                    function PassportAction(action){
                    var selectedPassport = document.getElementById('id_passport').value;
                    var linkElement=null;
                    var newHref='';
                    if(action=='ADD'){
                    linkElement=document.getElementById('AddClick');
                    newHref="{% url 'AddPassport' %}"
                    }
                    else if(action=='EDIT'){
                    linkElement=document.getElementById('EditClick');
                    newHref="{% url 'EditPassport' %}?passport_id=" + selectedPassport;
                    }else if(action=='VIEW'){
                    linkElement=document.getElementById('ViewClick');
                    newHref="{% url 'ViewPassport' %}?passport_id=" + selectedPassport;
                    }
                    linkElement.href = newHref;
                    alert(selectedPassport);
                    }
              </script>
```

**My Main Goal:**
**I want to create passport or visa within employee form same like in admin panel.**